# Make background service to show notification using socket.io

Tags: android, socket.io

I am developing android chat app. Firstly I create socket.io server using nodejs. Then from android I connected to server. My last task is to create service to show notification when application on foreground.

I create service like this:

```
public class BService extends Service {
public Socket mSocket;
public BService that = this;
Context ctx;
public static boolean isServiceRunning = false;
InfoSharedPreferences userInfoSharedP;                                    public BService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    userInfoSharedP = new InfoSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
        opts.secure = true;
        opts.transports = new String[]{WebSocket.NAME};
        opts.reconnection = true;
        opts.forceNew = true;

        mSocket = IO.socket("url",opts);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT,onConnect);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT,onDisconnect);
    mSocket.on("userInbox", userInbox);
    mSocket.connect();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ctx = getApplicationContext();
}

private void createNotification(String title,String text) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("ID", "Name", importance);
        Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), notificationChannel.getId());
    } else {
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    }

    builder = builder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logotext)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.logo))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setTicker(ctx.getString(R.string.newmessage))
            .setContentText(text)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ChatBoxActivity.class);

    android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatBoxActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        int mId = 9910;
        notificationManager.notify(mId, builder.build());
    }
}


private Emitter.Listener userInbox = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
        try {
            String message = data.getString("message");
            createNotification(ctx.getString(R.string.newmessage),message);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
               mSocket.emit("join", userInfoSharedP.getUserId());
            }
};

private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        if(!mSocket.connected())mSocket.connect();
    }
};


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    isServiceRunning = false;
    mSocket.emit("manual-disconnection", userInfoSharedP.getUserId()); 
    mSocket.disconnect();
    mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
    mSocket.off("userInbox", userInbox);
    mSocket.close();
}}
```

Everything works until the application is not killed within the process tray by the user.

How can I create service to show notification and to keep the Socket IO connection alive even if the application is killed?

Or how to make it with FCM + socket io service?

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot persist a Socket IO connection when the application is killed. In that case you'll have to use FCM, and maybe switch back to Socket IO when the user is interacting with the app.

Comment: @sbearben Can you show me example of this? FCM + socket.io ?